# Nodejs export not returning value

Tags: node.js, return, export

I have a nodejs export like this

```
exports.add = function(req){

    var newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    // Attempt to save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    });

}
```

But it's giving as undefined when i call the function like this

```
var value = instance.add(req);
```

Here instance is the imported instance of the javascript file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments by @Ben Fortune you couldn't simply return a value from an asynchronous function call. you should use **callbacks** or **promises**:

The **callback** way:

```
exports.add = function (req, callback) {

    var newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    // Attempt to save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        callback(null, newUser.toJSON()) ;
    });

}
```

Then:

```
instance.add(req, function(err, value) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // use value here
});
```

Read More: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) And implement **promise** way if you prefer.